# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. I tride socket.socket() and from socket import socket still not working

Tags: python, sockets

I have this code but it gives me this

```
  from socket import socket

     def main():
       host= "127.0.0.1"
       port = 5000
       s= socket()
       s.connect((host,port))
       message = raw_input
       while message != q:
          s.send(message)
          data = s.recv(1024)
          print "recieved from server: "+str(data)
          message = raw_input("->") 
       s.close()
       if __name__ == '__main__':
          main()
```

I am new to python, i am following a tutorial and this error does not happen in the tutorial I dont understand whats happening thans

Comment: What did you name this file? If the answer is `socket.py`, there's your problem. Or do you have a socket.py anywhere in your PATH?

Comment: I named it clientTcp.py, i dont know what is wrong i have python 2.7 version and i am using a remote machine from my university i do have a socket.py that mybe the problem

Comment: Yes, you will probably need to rename that file. Since python will first search for socket.py in you PATH, then it will use the built-in one

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are many errors in your script, this one should work:

```
import socket

def main():
   host= "127.0.0.1"
   port = 5000
   s= socket.socket() #Instead of s = socket()
   s.connect((host,port))
   while True:
        message = raw_input("->")
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print "recieved from server: "+str(data)

        if message == 'q':
            break
   s.close()

#This must be placed outside of the function 
#you want to call (in this case, main())

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

I hope this helps. Remember its always a good habit to review your code looking for typos and indentation errors.

Bye!